Chrome 125 - How to allow insecure content?
I'm unable to test file download with Selenium, after Chrome update to the version v125 (4.21.0).
i'm using Selenium 4.21.0 and Chrome 4.21.0 as webdriver.
Previously running Chrome with the '--disable-features=InsecureDownloadWarnings' arg did a trick for v122 (selenium/node-chrome 4.19.0)
Does anybody know if there is solution for this issue?
I noticed there is a bug raised here chromium but no solution as yet.
this is similar issue to  v122 but i'm using a different version of selenium and chrome.
I tried this with no luck --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://example.com

having the same issue... Was not able to find any solution yet
